# Missing mathtools.sty

Tags: packages

I'm really new to LaTeX and am having a problem with `mathtools.sty`. I am using MikTeX and Texmaker.

When I try to create the pdf (compile?) it gives me the error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `mathtools.sty' not found.Type X to quit or
>    to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter
>   file name:! Emergency stop. \usepackage

I looked this problem up on Google, and found a thread on this place. It said to open the Package Manager and download it there. I opened the Package manager, downloaded `mathtools` from it by pressing the "+". After doing this it still comes up with the same error, that `mathtools.sty` is missing.

I have tried reinstalling everything and still nothing works.

I really hope you can help and explain in a simple manner, so that even I can understand :)

Answer (score 2):

If your OS is windows:

1. Search for 'MikTex Console' and open it
2. Go to the Packages tab
3. Write the name of your package in the textbox
4. Click on the Plus button

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you launch MiKTeX Package Manager as administrator? That might explain. Always run as administrator if you want a system-wide installation (for any user).

Double-clicking on + installs the package, right-clicking on + only selects the package for further installation, this lets you select several packages then install them in a single stroke instead of one after the other. To install you have to right-click on the `mathtools` line and select `install`, or click on the `Tasks`menu and select ‘Install’. That's all.

Comment: You're right. I always used `+` with a right-click to select. I'll change that at once.

Comment: Yes i did open as administrator. 
I am now trying to find the file "mathtools.sty" on the internet, but it is nowhere to be found. I only get some useless "Latex-macros" files that i can't use for anything. 
I don't even know what folder to insert them into, there is no information for new guys like me at all. All the information is for people that already understands everything, and that is really annoying :(

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @Chen Stats: I don't remember where I gave some other hints, so I re-explain here: there has been a problem with mathtools recently, due to the splitting of the `mh` package in two parts (with different maintainers). You should first synchronise MiKTeX Package Manager (menu `Repository`-> `Synchronize`) to ensure the packages database is up-to-date. Then select `mathtools` in MPM, right-click on it and ask for installing it. That should be all you have to do

Comment: @Bernard After half an hour's research, I sorted it out. All I need to do , is to update my MixTex. THANKS!

Comment: @Chen Stats Yu: What do you mean, ‘sorting it out’? You didn't find the line with `mathtools` in MPM?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, sorted it out now. By default, MPM does not recognize the `mathtools.sty`, and can't be found in the package list. Many people had similar problems on stack exchange. I read loads of posts, now OK. Thanks again!

Comment: @Chen Stats Yu: it' the list if you synchronize, as I said. And you can find it quickly  entering the package name (or even part of its name) in the `Name` small window in MPM's tool bar, then clicking on the `Filter` button.

Comment: @Bernard The problem was that, the package was not listed in MPM. So I had to update it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17981/discussion-between-bernard-and-chen-stats-yu).

Answer (score 1):

You should install it manually.

- You can find `mathtools.sty` here: [mathtools.tds.zip](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools.tds.zip)
- unpack the whole content directly into `MikTeX 2.9` folder
- run `Maintenance (Admin)\Settings (Admin)`
- execute `Refresh FNDB` and `Update Formats`

and you're ready to use it!